How pass state or function from AG-Grid CellRenderer to its respective Parent Component?
I have a Tabs component, and AG-Grid lives within this Tabs component. The grid provides the user the option to view a document that is in the grid's data (image below).
In the image, you will see an icon shaped like an eye and when this eye button is clicked it should open a new tab and show a preview of the document. The issue I face is that the eye icon button lives inside a cellRenderer component so my question is a general question specific to cellRenderer which is how can I pass state/function from my cellRenderer to the parent component which is the TabsComponent so that when the eye icon is clicked then I can pass a state to the TabsComponent telling it to open a new tab to show the preview?
I know there is a cellRendererParams feature I can use however, this seems not to allow states or functions to be passed.
image description
